# dropdown popup window size issue on click in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I am using select list in HTML page:

```
<select id="Measures" onchange="CMG.CMGClass.LoadChartData(this.id)" 
        style="margin-top: 10px;width:200px" title="Select Option"> </select>
```

But whenever I click on select list item, some time list popup with dropdown width size & some times shows popup with more width than select list width.

I am facing this issue on IE 11. On IE 10, firefox and chrome its working fine-

Code to fill select list:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var select = document.getElementById("Measures");

        var options = {
            "table": [{ text: "SBP,DBP,Pulse" },
                       { text: "SBP,DBP,MAP,Pulse" },
                       { text: "SBP,DBP,Pulse,Temp" },
                       { text: "SBP,DBP,Pulse,RR" },
                       { text: "SBP,DBP,Pulse,Temp,O2 Sat" },
                       { text: "Pulse,RR,O2 Sat" },
                       { text: "Height,Weight,BMI" }
            ]
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < options.table.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = options.table[i].text.trim();
            opt.value = options.table[i].text.trim();
            select.appendChild(opt);
        }
});
```

What to do?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDpxz/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just the way that IE 10 and 11 work.

Do you still see the problem [here?](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)

As an alternative to using a regular HTML select, you could try using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). This gives you the freedom to style it however you want.

Comment: @Does the problem still happen at the link I posted? I can't replicate anything wrong on IE11.

Comment: Hi, your link is working fine on IE 11 also. But in my page when we change any  new selected item & click again to change selection next time its popup width get doubled than select control width & blank space . if i select same item again &  click again for selection second time  its showing pop up in proper select control width (new item selection first click its getting this issue.) Thanks for reply

Comment: @JaydipPatil What you're describing does not happen in your jsfiddle for my IE11. You must have a non-default setup. See if you can disable any add-ons, make sure your zoom is set to 100%, check your Internet Options, etc... I'm sorry I can't be more help.